# Server in '/' Application error in browser, command line cannot curl to URL

Tags: .net, ssl, tls1.2

I'm looking for some advice on where next to troubleshoot. If you can give me an idea for what to try next, I would be most appreciative.
I've got an app that needs to get out to an external URI via HTTPS to give users a PDF, but in the browser session users always get the HTML error below instead of the PDF.
 It seems to be related to SSL/TLS, but nothing I do seems to make a difference. I went through a whole cycle of disabling and enabling various pieces of SSL3, TLS, TLS11, TLS12, etc, but nothing worked. I've tried forcing the TLS to 1.2 in the registry (and rebooted) but that hasn't worked, and when I run

> invoke-webrequest https://website.net

using the parameter -UseBasicParsing in powershell it'll work in the command line. Leave off the parameter and you get an error saying the IE Engine isn't installed (headless server 2016, so no IE). 
The server is running on a VMWare VM.
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3535.0

I recently loaded the latest MS Patch KB4534271.
 It mentions cryptography, so it could be part of the problem.
The server runs through a load balancer for inbound traffic, but this outbound request to the external server URL isn't routed through the load balancer, and I've already checked the LB and FW logs to confirm they arent blocking anything.

**Any ideas?**

**Systeminfo**

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Server
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Windows User
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                00377-70062-08542-AA680
Original Install Date:     5/20/2019, 11:37:53 PM
System Boot Time:          1/16/2020, 5:49:16 PM
System Manufacturer:       VMware, Inc.
System Model:              VMware Virtual Platform
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              2 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2095 Mhz
                           [02]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2095 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Phoenix Technologies LTD 6.00, 12/12/2018
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     32,768 MB
Available Physical Memory: 30,557 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  37,632 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 35,460 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    2,172 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    domain.net
Logon Server:              \nameofADserver
Hotfix(s):                 9 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB4033393
                           [02]: KB4049065
                           [03]: KB4054590
                           [04]: KB4498947
                           [05]: KB4503537
                           [06]: KB4509091
                           [07]: KB4520724
                           [08]: KB4521858
                           [09]: KB4534271
Network Card(s):           1 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet0
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: internalIPaddress
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.

**Changes made in Registry**
    `Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord`

```
`Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord`
```

**ERROR I GET in command line:**

> invoke-webrequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing
>   parameter and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + invoke-webrequest https://website.net
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], NotSupportedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
> WebCmdletIEDomNotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

**ERROR IN WEB BROWSER (pretty generic):**

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.]
>      System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) +322
>      System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +137
>
> [HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
>
> [AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) +4761032
>      WebCenter.Web.Areas.Employee.Controllers.PayHistoryController.W2Merge(Int32 id, Boolean isW2C) >+1438
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +199
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, >IDictionary`2 parameters) +280
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, >ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +33
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) >+42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +80
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +387
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +387
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +387
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +387
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +387
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +187
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +602
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3535.0

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this case was to load the following commands in the registry via powershell and force the computer to use TLS 1.2 in all sessions. Ugly, but it got the job done.

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord